# Consolidating Office 365, AAD and Azure Subscription

Tags: active-directory, azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

my current situation is as follows:

- We are running an Azure subscription that was set up with a PERSONAL Windows Live account, but the account has been set up using an email address from our actual domain.
- We have an Exchange 2013/O365 hybrid setup, with our AD syncing with O365. We have a mixture of on-premise mailboxes, E1 and E3 licenced users with mailboxes in O365.

My ultimate goal is have our local AD syncing with Azure and O365, with true SSO for users.

Forgetting the SSO bit for now (unless it has relevance at this stage), I just need to know how I can move my existing Azure subscription from the personal account into our existing Azure AD that O365 is using.

If someone can point me in the right direction as the process I need to go through I'd appreciate it.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think you yourself can move it very easily (things might have changed since last I tried). I think Azure support can merge subscriptions. If not, your only option might be to start a new Azure subscription by logging into the portal **using an Office 365 global admin account** and then manually migrate everything from one subscription to the other.

Comment: This article about transferring subscriptions to another account owner probably applies to you. You can do this online. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer

Comment: John. You are a legend. I can’t believe it was that simple. Not only has it transferred ownership to my corporate account, the subscription has automatically been transferred into our active Azure AD directory that is used by O365. That is exactly what I was after. All the articles I read suggested this was not possible without MS support getting involved. Thank you!!!

Comment: John, post your comment as an answer and I’ll mark it as the accepted solution for you.

Comment: Thank you @TonyBlunt - I love the competition between the big three Cloud providers. Lots of excellent services and features. I can only imagine what we will have in another 10 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article about transferring subscriptions to another account owner probably applies to you. You can do this online.

[Transfer ownership of an Azure subscription to another account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer)

Comment: Thanks John, this is exactly what I was after, and given the info on the net I was surprised how painless this was. Not only has this made my corporate account the owner, after another 5-10 mins, it had automatically moved the subscription into the existing AAD directory I have in my O365 hybrid.

Answer (score 2):

If possible you will have to call support to get them to migrate your subscription.  There is no self service option to migrate the subscription from your Microsoft account to your organizational account.

Comment: Thanks, I feared this might be the case. Involving support might mean a bit of work for me prior to contacting them - a hybrid Exch2013/O365 setup is only supported if the server is on the latest CU. When I set this up (only 6 months ago at the most), CU16 was the current CU, which I upgraded to prior to setting up the hybrid. Now it seems that we've moved onto CU19 and I missed the boat on that one. I'll upgrade to CU19 and then call support. Thanks.

Comment: Billing/account support, to move subscriptions around, won't give a toss (or even ask) about your on-prem technology versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but we are talking about two different things. One is, who pays the bill? and the other one, which Azure AD tenant has ownership of my subscriptions?

First work with your EA provider to enable Azure services for you. They might even help you with the transfer of the subscriptions, but a commitment is probably required. EA is not paid on a monthly basis as it is PaYG, but you would be surprised by the discount that you get for compute and storage costs. So I'd recommend talking to you EA provider.

**Migrating the offer:**

To migrate the subscription, all you have to do is follow this guide:

> Can I migrate from Pay-As-You-Go to Cloud Solution Provider (CSP) or
>   Enterprise Agreement (EA)?
>
> To migrate to CSP, see Azure Pas-As-You-Go Subscription Migration to
>   CSP.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cloud-solution-provider/migration/migration-from-payg-to-csp
>
> To migrate to EA, have your Enrollment Admin add your account
>   into the EA. Follow instructions in the invitation email to have your
>   subscriptions moved under EA enrollment. To learn more, see Associate
>   an Existing Account in the EA portal.
>
> https://ea.azure.com/helpdocs/associateExistingAccount

More info here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-how-to-switch-azure-offer

**Migrating the directory:**

Now, to change the directory associated with the subscription, that is, from your personal Azure AD tenant to your corporate Azure AD tenant, follow this guide:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being a bit thick, but I don't have an EA provider, or even really know what one is. Do you mean a 3rd party hosting provider? If so, I don't have one as I simply configured the Azure environment myself, using a PAYG subscription.

Comment: You have enterprise O365 accounts so I assumed that you had acquired the licenses through an LSP (license service provider), but I guess you can also buy E1 and E3 with a credit card. So, all you have basically is to change the Azure AD associated with your subscription. Your O365 is sitting on top of one Azure AD tenant and the Azure subscriptions in another. Basically, you just need to follow the guidance on my last link. Microsoft might be able to do this for you though.

Comment: You can also go to a CSP

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the clarification, but I don’t think it as simple as that for me. The directory my Azure subscription is in is associated with a Personal live ID, which whilst uses the same email domain as our corporate accounts used by O365, it had no association at all. I won’t be able to simply move my subscription as per the link as the directory my O365 uses won’t be available from there. From the info here and other resources, I think this is a task I need to ask support to assist with.