# Combine / Allow access between 2 Azure / Office 365 Domains / Tenants

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id, entra-domain-services

Apologies if this is not the correct place to ask this question.

After a recent acquisition, I am trying to understand if it is possible to provide a trust between 2 Office 365/Azure AD domains, both are currently syncing via separate Azure AD Connects in 2 different regions.

Is it possible to do this without setting up an AD trust on premise? We're looking away from this option for security reasons.

I've come across something called Azure AD B2B. Will that help in what I am trying to achieve?

Or is there a way for a single global admin account in Azure to allow and control access between the 2 online domains? Perhaps using the method as described here:
[Consolidating Office 365, AAD and Azure Subscription](https://serverfault.com/questions/893719/consolidating-office-365-aad-and-azure-subscription)

What are the limitations if any?

Is it possible for company A using 123.com email addresses to create accounts for company B's 789.com email address and vice versa?

Can the calendar free/busy lookups work between the domains?

I know I'm possibly asking the impossible, but any help/insight would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a 1:1 relationship between the on-prem domain and entra id domain when using Azure aad connect.

But there is an exception you can add multiple domains to azure ad connect.
So you could create a S2S-VPN to the other company and their domain controller and sync the users.

Another option would be a tenant-to-tenant migration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-tenant-to-tenant-migrations?view=o365-worldwide